# Splitting Data Frame with Specific Suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to split based on the column names' suffix of `_x` or `_y`. Column names with the suffix `_x` should form one dataframe and column names with the suffix `_y` should form the other dataframe. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**For example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.rename(columns={'A':'A_x', 'B':'B_y','C':'C_x', 'D':'D_y'}, inplace=True)

df
   A_x  B_y  C_x  D_y
0    8    8    0    8
1    3    2    9    8
2    2    6    7    9
3    4    1    7    7
4    9    6    3    2
5    3    3    0    3
6    9    5    6    8
7    3    7    9    0
8    4    2    6    4
9    8    5    8    2
```

**Wanted Output:**

df1

```
   A_x  C_x
0    8    0
1    3    9
2    2    7
3    4    7
4    9    3
5    3    0
6    9    6
7    3    9
8    4    6
9    8    8
```

df2

```
 B_y  D_y
0    8    8
1    2    8
2    6    9
3    1    7
4    6    2
5    3    3
6    5    8
7    7    0
8    2    4
9    5    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest and easiest to use with regex `df.filter`:

You can refer the [Documentation here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

**Actual DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
   A_x  B_y  C_x  D_y
0    8    9    5    1
1    3    4    0    6
2    9    7    0    4
3    6    7    5    9
4    4    3    7    5
5    6    1    6    9
6    5    4    5    4
7    8    3    0    1
8    7    4    4    4
9    9    2    4    4
```

**Apply `dataFrame.filter` :**

```
>>> df1 = df.filter(regex='_x')
>>> df2 = df.filter(regex='_y')
```

**Your Splitted New DataFrame `df1`**

```
>>> df1
   A_x  C_x
0    8    5
1    3    0
2    9    0
3    6    5
4    4    7
5    6    6
6    5    5
7    8    0
8    7    4
9    9    4
```

**Your Splitted New DataFrame `df2`**

```
>>> df2
   B_y  D_y
0    9    1
1    4    6
2    7    4
3    7    9
4    3    5
5    1    9
6    4    4
7    3    1
8    4    4
9    2    4
```

**OR : `DataFrame.filter` with `regex` which uses `re.search` under the hood.**

```
>>> df1 = df.filter(regex='x$', axis=1)
>>> df2 = df.filter(regex='y$', axis=1)
```

**OR:  `DataFrame.filter` with Parameter `like`**

```
df1, df2 = df.filter(like='_x'), df.filter(like='_y')
```

**OR: Using `dataFrame.loc` + `contains`**

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('_x')]
df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('_x')]
```

**OR: Using `dataFrame.loc` + `map` with `lambda` + `endswith`**

```
df1 = df.loc[:,df.columns.map(lambda x: x.endswith('_x'))]
df2 = df.loc[:,df.columns.map(lambda x: x.endswith('_y'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using `split` with columns , the we do `groupby` , save them into dict .Notice this method is easy to apply more cases, for example : you have more than 1000 columns with different suffix like _x _y _z _c _a.....

```
d={x:y for x, y in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[1],axis=1)}
d['x']
   A_x  C_x
0    8    0
1    3    9
2    2    7
3    4    7
4    9    3
5    3    0
6    9    6
7    3    9
8    4    6
9    8    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply do:

```
df1=df[['A_x','C_x']]
df2=df[['B_y','D_y']]
```

Then now `df1` and `df2` are expected data-frames.

More unspecific:

```
df1=df[[i for i in df.columns if i[-1]=='x']]
df2=df[[i for i in df.columns if i[-1]=='y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `endswith` for column names?

```
df1 = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.endswith('_x')]]
df2 = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.endswith('_y')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Since indexing in python starts from 0, so You can use

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, [0,2]]
df2 = df.iloc[:, [1,3]]
```

Method 2: Since here the column names are known so you can also use

```
df1=df[['A_x','C_x']]
df2=df[['B_y','D_y']]
```

Both these methods will give the same answers